# Xamarin component.exe is not opening on Windows

Tags: windows, xamarin, xamarin-component

I have downloaded the [XPGK](https://components.xamarin.com/submit/xpkg) `.zip` archive to be able to upload my component to the Xamarin Store. I have done so by following the first step of [this guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/submitting_components/component_submission_quickstart/#Create_the_Component).

But when I click the `.exe` file a command prompt file just appears and disappears? What's the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you follow the [guide](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/advanced/submitting_components/component_submission_quickstart/)? It doesn't mention that you should click the `.exe` file to open it. Instead, the `.exe` file is used to generate the directory structure required for your component.

> Use the xamarin-component.exe to create the base structure by typing the following into the console/terminal where is the base folder for your component.
>
> Note: you will need to change the path to the location where you extracted the ".exe” file.

This means that you should first extract the `.exe` file to a directory where you want your solution to be placed (most likely your workspace).

Then, using a console/terminal, navigate to the directory in which you extracted the `.exe` file and type the following:

For Windows:

```
xamarin-component.exe create <foldername>
```

for OS X:

```
mono xamarin-component.exe create <foldername>
```

Where `<foldername>` is the name you want your directory to be.